# jQuery Trouble with ie7 .parents .find

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

This code works fine except in ie7 and 8

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#buchen li').load('buchen.html');
    $(".nav-three").click(function(){
        var reisename = $(this).parents(".kurzreise").find("h3").text();

 <!--Up until here everything seems fine. The var "reisename" contains the text it should.-->

        $(this).parents(".kurzreise").find("#reiseziel").text(reisename);
        $(this).parents(".kurzreise").find("#reiseziel").val(reisename);
    });
});
```

When trying to write the text in the div "#reiseziel", nothing happens in ie7. 
I think it could either have something to do with the fact that I load the "buchen.html" via query into another html-page. 
Or is there a known problem with the .parents or .find ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could change it to use the ajax function instead and handle your dynamic content inside the success?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'buchen.html',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#buchen li').append(data);
        // Maybe put your stuff here.

        $(this).parents(".kurzreise").find("#reiseziel").text(reisename);
        $(this).parents(".kurzreise").find("#reiseziel").val(reisename);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Zach, I tried your solution. The same results came up. Still ie7 doesn't show a thing while the other browsers have no problem.
So now I'm guessing, the problem lies in this line:

    $(this).parents(".kurzreise").find("#reiseziel").text(reisename);

any idea, what ie couldn't like about that line?

Comment: I would need to see the html... perhaps you could change parents to closest? It will stop after it finds the first one and it includes "this" in the check - see if that works - even if you have more than one .kurzeise.   $(this).closest(".kurzreise").find("#reiseziel").text(reisename);

Comment: Another thing you could do would be to put the data that you load dynamically on the page statically and test. If it works that way, then we've narrowed it down.  Edit - is .nav-three loaded in dynamically with the .load()?